# threading.Thread against multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

So recently I had the following problem : I have to make a server that handle request in order to update some values while the main process is using this values. **So here, the server handling function is in the subprocess, and I can't stop it when i want.**

In order to test what was the best solution for my problem between `threading.Thread` or `multiprocessing.Process`, I made this little following program :

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import threading

class SubProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        super(SubProcess, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1) # Waiting for request...
            self.source.somevar["anotherkey"].append(5)
            print "My subprocess : ", id(self.source), id(self.source.somevar), self.source.somevar

class SubThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        super(SubThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1) # Waiting for request...
            self.source.somevar["anotherkey"].append(5)
            print "My subthread : ", id(self.source), id(self.source.somevar), self.source.somevar

class Source:

    def __init__(self):
        self.somevar = {"akey": "THE key", "anotherkey": [5]}

    def start_process(self):
        self.process = SubProcess(self)
        self.process.start()

    def stop_process(self):
        self.process.terminate()

    def start_thread(self):
        self.thread = SubThread(self)
        self.thread.start()

    def stop_thread(self):
        # self.thread.stop() # What the hell should i put here
        pass

s = Source()

s.start_process()
time.sleep(2)
print "End : ", id(s), id(s.somevar), s.somevar
s.stop_process()

s.start_thread()
time.sleep(2)
print "End : ", id(s), id(s.somevar), s.somevar
s.stop_thread() # Obviously, thread never ends...
```

So `threading.Thread` modify the original `s.somevar` but I can't stop it, while `multiprocessing.Process` doesn't modify the original `s.somevar` but i can stop it.

I'm looking for a solution where I can stop the thread (with a SIGTERM) and where the thread can modify the original class `Source`, **using the standard library**. Is there any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. See [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) for a discussion of options - but these are co-operative! If that's not possible, use multiprocessing + messages to update a copy of the state locally.

Answer (score 1):

To kill the thread, you need do something co-operative between the sub-thread and the main thread. With your example code, you could use a `threading.Event`:

```
class SubThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        self.should_stop = threading.Event()
        super(SubThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while not self.should_stop.wait(1):
            #time.sleep(1) # No need to sleep, since we're waiting for 1 second above.
            self.source.somevar["anotherkey"].append(5)
            print "My subthread : ", id(self.source), id(self.source.somevar), self.source.somevar

    def stop(self):
        """ Call this to abort the thread. """
        self.should_stop.set()
```

This isn't as immediate a termination as it can be with `process.terminate()`, since you have to actually hit the call to `should_stop.wait()` before the thread is stopped.

To make the `SubProcess` work correctly, you need to use a process-safe shared variable. The `multiprocessing` module provides `multiprocessing.Manager` for this; it allows you to create shared variables in a manager process. The way you're updating the dict is actually a little tricky to handle properly though, because of some limitations with changing mutable values inside of the `Proxy` objects you get back from the `Manager` (see the note from the on that [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list)). You have to explicitly re-assign the updated list to the dict for the dict to be updated properly:

```
class SubProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        super(SubProcess, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1) # Waiting for request...
            # Can't do this with a Manager.dict
            #self.source.somevar["anotherkey"].append(5)

            # Do this instead. You'd need to do it with SubThread.run, too.
            l = self.source.somevar["anotherkey"]
            l.append(5)
            self.source.somevar["anotherkey"] = l
            print "My subprocess : ", id(self.source), id(self.source.somevar), self.source.somevar

class Source:

    def __init__(self):
        self.m = multiprocessing.Manager()
        # somevar is now process-safe.
        self.somevar = self.m.dict({"akey": "THE key", "anotherkey": [5]})

    # The rest is the same
```